# How to use custom background picture in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: desktop-background

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 I can't find a way to chose a custom picture as desktop background.
I tried **System settings -> Background**, but this menu does not provide any file picker to choose a picture but shows only the preinstalled pictures:

[image]

Or an empty window:

[image]

I can't find the options to set how the picture ought to be displayed either (like stretch or scale)

Do I have to install Cinnamon desktop just to be able to change my background picture? How can I do it with Ubuntu?

Comment: I think the problem might be, that I installed Gnome-Desktop and that it's packages overrides Ubuntus standard background dialogue. Does anybody know how to change that back?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to that?

Comment: No, if you don't use Unitiy, which renders the desktop in Ubuntu, you stick with this ridiculous menu from the crazy gnome guys. You can't choose a file from your computer but from Flikr. Brave new world!

Answer (score 4):

There area several ways built-in to Ubuntu 13.10. Though it is curious that your screen shots look far different than mine.

**Option 1**:
right click the desktop and select '**Change Desktop background**'
[image]

Click on the '**+**' button to bring up a dialog box to select an image
[image]

[image]

or

Select '**Pictures Folder**' from the drop down to select an image in your pictures folder
[image]

**Option 2**:
Open an image in IMage Viewer. Right click somewhere on the image and select '**Set as Wallpaper**'.
[image]

**Option 3**:
Find an image using Firefox. Right click on it and select '**Set As Desktop Background**'
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try **[Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/)**

**Installing Variety**

- open terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute these commands to add repository and install it.

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install variety
  ```
- Then open `variety` from *Dash*
- And get started to dig a lot of features. The more you dig the more features and wallpaper you'll get.

[image]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]
[image: image5]

<sub>[Source: peterlevi.com/variety/](http://peterlevi.com/variety/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Install `dconf-tools` with:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

In the dash type **dconf** and start the *dconf-editor*. Select *org -> gnome -> desktop -> background* and change the value of **picture-uri** with the file you want.

Syntax:

```
file://<full_name_of_the_image_file>
```

Here's a visual aid for this:
[image: snap]

---

Or open the image file with any image viewer, right click on the image and select *Set as Desktop Background*.
[image: snap02]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try moving the wallpaper image you want to use into `/usr/share/backgrounds`.

1. Execute this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo -H nautilus $HOME
   ```
2. Locate the wallpaper image you want to use and 'Copy' it.
3. Navigate to the `/usr/share/backgrounds` folder by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and entering that path. Alternatively, just browse into the folder.
4. 'Paste' the image you want to use into that folder.
5. Try selecting the image in "System Settings → Background".

Answer (score 0):

Try **System Settings > Appearance > Look > Background** tab, there is a dropdown box where you can select **Pictures Folder**. It allows you to use the file picker to select the background.

Answer (score 0):

Find the picture you want in your file explorer, then right click it and select the "desktop background" option. Then a box will pop up that will give you more options for how it looks.