# Dual monitor lubuntu how to change wallpaper in extended screen?

Tags: lubuntu, screen, desktop-background

Hi I have dual monitor in lubuntu. The main screen is 1280x800 and the extended screen is 1024x768.
I installed variety. It changes wallpaper every 5 minutes.
However it changes wallpaper only in main screen. In the extended screen the wallpaper stays always the same. It is the default lubuntu wallpaper. I tried to change wallpaper in extended screen using nitrogen but nothing happens. How to change wallpaper in extended screen?

Answer (score 2):

This is a super-old question, but I was annoyed by the issue today and finally found a solution. Note that this might only apply to **LXDE**, not to LXQt and hence might not be applicable for recent lubuntu versions.

The right way to do this is to have two files `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE/desktop-items-0.conf` and `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE/desktop-items-1.conf`.
The former holds the config for the first desktop, the second for the second desktop. The desktop settings utility only covers the first one, so you'll need to change the various `wallpaper=` values manually with an editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution.

I downloaded and installed disper-indicator. It is a .deb package.
I installed it manually because I could not find it in repositories. 
Then I have set disper-indicator to run on startup. So now I click on disper indicator and I configure the dual monitors

---

Disper indicator can be found from this repository https://launchpad.net/~nmellegard/+archive/ubuntu/disper-indicator-ppa

<sup>Added later by Edit</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this same issue on Lubuntu 14.04 and it was driving me crazy. I changed the desktop wallpaper multiple times and ways, including even using Nitrogen and SyncWall both mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390367/using-different-wallpapers-on-multiple-monitors-gnome-2-compiz).

What worked for me was running the following:

`pcmanfm --desktop-off`

from a terminal window.

I hope that helps some wandering soul that is trying to set multiple monitors with different wallpapers. I found the help on an [old archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=158852) of all places.