# How do I switch my monitors separately on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, multiple-monitors, workspace-switcher

I have two monitors, and would like each monitor to have its own desktop wall. I did some Googling, installed CompizConfig Settings Manager, and changed `Desktop Wall => Viewport Switching => Multimonitor Behavior` from `Switch all` to `Switch separately`.

I've tried all of the usual debugging steps (restarted, disabled/enabled the Desktop Wall plugin, toggled the setting a couple times) to no avail.

Any ideas on some things I might try to get this working?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: bump. Experiencing the exact same problem here. Happy to help debugging.

Comment: Is this solved ?

Comment: @ankit7540 Nope, I was never able to find a solution.

Comment: The answer to your question is here [dual monitors-> different wallpapers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/390367/using-different-wallpapers-on-multiple-monitors-gnome-2-compiz). If any question about setting up then ask.

Answer (score -1):

You might try the tool Nitrogen.

Get it from the official Ubuntu repositories with the command: 
sudo apt-get install nitrogen

Pull it up into the GUI from the command line with:
nitrogen

Go to preferences, add your folder which contains your wallpapers, and screen 1, 2, etc to set different wallpapers for different monitors.

Answer (score -1):

What I do is go into system settings (unity) and select display. You see 2 rectangles, each represents a monitor. I click the one marked #2 and drag it to the left side of number #1, then click apply, finally drag the mouse pointer to the edge of one screen, bounce is around the corner till it shows up on the other screen which, now shows the screen originally on the first monitor, goto the display gui still showing and click on the box that says something like mirror on each."