# Nitrogen missing an option

Tags: desktop-background

Now this may be a stupid question maybe just an update, but it could also be that nitrogen for some reason isn't aware of me having two displays since the option I'm missing seems to be the one where to select which screen a wallpaper goes on. I was trying to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390367/using-different-wallpapers-on-multiple-monitors-gnome-2-compiz) answer. [Image of my nitrogen window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXdNi.png)

Comment: was it ever the case before? what is your distro? distro version? and desktop environement?

Comment: that guide worked on ubuntu 13.04 it's not surprising things broke down in the meantime. I imagine nitrogen is not the optimal solution for dual wallpapers for ubuntu 18+ EDIT indeed... https://itsfoss.com/wallpaper-multi-monitor/

Comment: @MiilaVuorio if my answer helped, please mark it and upvote it so that other people may also benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

would you be open to a more modern (and more akin to 18.04/19.04) solution ?

if so then run  (this will reboot your system when it's done) :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak -y && sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo && sudo reboot
```

then open up the software center and type "HydraPaper" and install what comes up.

then you may run HydraPaper and :

[image: set different wallpapers per monitor]

for future reference you can check (and always should check) the date of a question/answer like so : 
[image: date question]

the "Dec '13'13" in that rectangle translates to "the 13th of december in 2013"

the user states he is using ubuntu 13.04 right after his diagram.